# Writing A File to Download Folder (Android 11 SDK 30)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm developing an applicaiton using Android 11 and Kotlin. I've successfully written a file to the Download folder on the device. When writing to the folder again using the same file name, the result is another file with the same name. So now I have two files with the same name.

[image]

So first I thought I'd just delete the file then write it again. I spent hours and hours trying that to no avail. The delete code would execute without exception but the file would never delete. I'm pretty sure I set the proper permissions by using

```
  if (!isWriteExternalStoragePermissionGranted()) {
            val permissions = arrayOf(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            for (i in permissions.indices) {
                requestPermission(permissions[i], i)
            }
        }


 private fun isWriteExternalStoragePermissionGranted(): Boolean {
        val permissionCheck = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,  WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        return permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }
```

Then I thought I'd truncate the contents of the file and just overwrite the files contents. That didn't work. Just annother copy of file again and again. I have spent almpost a full day on this. It really shouldn't be this hard. I've tried numerous examples.. nothing works. Here's my code to write the file...

```
 fun writeToFile(applicationContext: Context, filename: String, data: String) {

    try {
        val resolver = applicationContext.contentResolver
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, filename)
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "text/xml")
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
        val uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), values)

        //val cr: ContentResolver = getContentResolver()
        val os: OutputStream? = uri?.let { resolver.openOutputStream(it,"wt") }

        if (os != null) {
            os.write(data.toByteArray())
            os.flush()
            os.close()
        }
        /*
        if (uri != null) {
            resolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "wt")?.use {
                FileOutputStream(it.fileDescriptor).use {
                     it.write(data.toByteArray()
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        */

        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
}
```

Here's my code to delete the file first that never works. I've tried multiple variations...

```
fun deleteFile(context: Context, filename: String, applicationContext: Context){

    val myFile = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), filename)
    if (myFile.exists()) {
        myFile.delete()
    }
}


fun deleteFile(context: Context, filename: String, applicationContext: Context){

    val resolver = applicationContext.contentResolver
    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, filename)
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "text/xml")
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
    val uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), values)

    if (uri != null) {
        resolver.delete(uri, null, null)
    }

}
```

Comment: You only have read/write access to files in `Downloads` that your app installation created. You have no access to files in `Downloads` from other apps or previous installations of your own app, where the app had been uninstalled and then reinstalled. So, perhaps the original `scanned_bar_codes.xml` file was created by some previous installation of your app.

Comment: `the result is another file with the same name. ` That does not very much look like the same file name.

Comment: The first deleteFile() is nonsense. The second too as you did a new insert() and hence obtained a new uri. Instead you should use the uri you got with the first insert() where you created the file.

Comment: that second file the (1) is the result of the insert. In other words, the "create file funciton just creates a 2nd, 3rd file and so on.  It's as though I do a copy and paste of the original file in the same directory... follow?

Comment: I simply want to do this..  Write a file to the Dowload folder.  At some later point in time write a file with the same name to the Download folder.  But..BEFORE doing doing that, delete the file already in the Download folder with that same name. Then write the file.

That.. or just open the existing file in that Download folder...and just overwrite the contents of the file with new data

Comment: I already told you how to do that. But apparently you could not follow. ;-)

Comment: I get it now.. what you said.  I need to use the uri when i create the file to delete that file.  I just implemented that in my code. It works now.  Not getting duplicate files now. Thanks.

Comment: blackapps - how do I give you credit for answering my post/question?  Showing the question is answered?

Comment: @Beachdog tap the triangle pointing up next tp his comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the uri you got with the first insert() where you created the file.

Comment: After writing the file, if i open the downloads folder programmatically using startActivity(Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS)). File is not visible. But if i open from file explorer of phone, then the file is visible.  Any idea, why this is happening ?

Comment: Sorry, dont know.